# Button in Custom Dialog does not work (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom dialog box with a Next button that is supposed to trigger an alert box to appear. However nothing happens when I click on Next.

**Code.gs:**

```
function createInvoice() {

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile("CreateInvoice1");

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Create New Invoice");

}
```

**CreateInvoice1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="CreateInvoice1form">
     <div class="block form-group">
         <label for="select"> Select Client:</label>
         <select id="select">
           <option value="Cl01">Client 1</option>
           <option value="Cl02">Client 2</option>
         </select>
     </div>
     <br><br> 
     <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="Next1()">
     <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
   </form> 

   <script>
   function Next1() {
     var selectedClient = document.getElementbyId("select").value;

     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You are making an invoice for"+selectedClient);
   }
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `alert("You are making an invoice for"+selectedClient);` instead?  google.script.run is used to call a server side function in one of the .gs files.

Comment: I just tried that and still nothing happens when the button is clicked. @Karl_S

Comment: @frebs [Edit] your code to show the latest code( with modifications as suggested by Karl).

Comment: @TheMaster noted, code has been edited to omit the `google.script.run`, if I'm right in my understanding that it is not needed to call the `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()`

Comment: @frebs wrong. Just plain `alert('Hello World');` Remove `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`

Comment: Also, are there any errors in the Console of the browser's developer tools?  There you should see a message for an uncaught error _document.getElementbyId is not a function_ because it needs an uppercase B:  document.getElementById

Comment: Also, your function is declared after it's used in the `onclick()`. If you click it before the document is fully loaded, The function will be undefined. Move the script parts to the head or disable clicks until  the document is loaded.

Comment: @TheMaster is right. Do not mix client side script with server side objects such as SpreadsheetApp, Simply use alert().

Comment: dropping `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` and using the uppercase B in `getElementById` did the trick. Thank you everyone for all your help! I'm gaining a better understanding of client-side and server-side concepts now.

Comment: @frebs  Kindly add your solution in the answer box below and not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution (.html)**

- Placed the script in the head as best practice
- Used correct case as in: getElementById
- dropped server side object to call the alert prompt

```
<head>
   <script>
   function Next1() {
     var selectedClient = document.getElementById("select").value;

     alert("You are making an invoice for"+selectedClient);
   }
   </script>
</head>
```